# Executing ssh commands on by one in shell using jsch ssh

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to execute some tool in unix using the jsch ssh class (com.jcraft.jsch).
My tool have a selection menu.
I need to go to the folder where the tool is place, execute it and select the requested options.
After each command, (cd, execute, ...) I wish to examine the output and check the status code (0/1).
I have the following code that execute it as expected but in this code I couldn't find a way how to examine the output after each command.

```
Session session = _getConnectedSession(); 
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
channel.connect();

InputStream is = channel.getInputStream();
BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());  

// send ls command to the server  
enter code here dataOut.writeBytes("cd tools; run tool\n");  
dataOut.writeBytes("4\r\n");  // option 4 in the tool
dataOut.writeBytes("4\r\n");  // then, option 4 in the tool
dataOut.writeBytes("6\r\n");  // then, option 6 in the tool
dataOut.writeBytes("n\r\n");  // then, option n in the tool
dataOut.flush();
String line = dataIn.readLine();

while ((line = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

if(channel.isClosed()){
    system.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());       
}

dataIn.close();  
dataOut.close();  
channel.disconnect();  
session.disconnect();
```

I couldn't find a way yet how can I separate the commands and print them one by one (in while loop) and not as I did above.

I have tried to split all commands to two bulks as following but it prints and execute only the first bulk of commands (before the first while loop):

```
// First bulk of commands
enter code here dataOut.writeBytes("cd tools; run tool\n");  
dataOut.writeBytes("4\r\n");  // option 4 in the tool
dataOut.writeBytes("4\r\n");  // then, option 4 in the tool
dataOut.flush();

String line = dataIn.readLine();
while ((line = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

// Second bulk of commands
dataOut.writeBytes("6\r\n");  // then, option 6 in the tool
dataOut.writeBytes("n\r\n");  // then, option n in the tool
dataOut.flush();
line = dataIn.readLine();
while ((line = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}


if(channel.isClosed()){
    system.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());       
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it hanging in the `.readLine()` call? have you tried using `.read()` instead? Probably your tool is writing something after the second "option 4" but not a line terminator.

Comment: It looks that `.read()` returns Int (not string). In my case, the input is not necessarily a number... I think that it get the new line after the second '4' because when it run in one bulk it works fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you haven't set the output stream and to check the exit status of the last executed command you have to use

**"$?" - if it is 0 last executed command is successful otherwise it is failure.**

The below code snippet allows you to give commands and read the response code of that command.

```
                ss=new StringBuilder("ls | echo $?");
                ss.append("\n");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("comm.txt");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(ss.toString());
                bw.flush();
                fw.close();
                bw.close();
                InputStream is=new FileInputStream("comm.txt");
                OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("outs.txt");   
                channel.setInputStream(is);
                channel.setOutputStream(os);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                channel.connect();
                System.out.println("connected");
                f.dispose();
                getApplication();
```

**In the above code I have used "comm.txt" as inputstream and "outs.txt" as output stream. You can change the content of stringBuilder object by using Scanner class.**

> ls | echo $?"

will produce 0 if ls is executed successfully otherwise non-zero value. This value can be checked in outs.txt file.

If the content of outs.txt file is 0 the command is executed correctly otherwise it is not executed properly. You have to write code to read contents from outs.txt file.

If you want the full code you can see my project

> [GITHUB](https://github.com/sridharan99/Cloud)

In that see "Cloud.java" file for full code.